# React, insert/append/render existing <HTMLCanvasElement>

Tags: reactjs, canvas

In my `<App> Context`, I have a canvas element (`#offScreen`) that is already hooked in the `requestAnimationFrame` loop and appropriately drawing to that canvas, verified by `.captureStream` to a `<video>` element.

In my `<Canvas>` react component, I have the following code (which works, but seems clunky/not the best way to copy an offscreen canvas to the DOM):

*NOTE*: `master` is the data object for the `<App> Context`.

```
function Canvas({ master, ...rest } = {}) {
    const canvasRef = useRef(master.canvas);
    
    const draw = ctx => {
        ctx.drawImage(master.canvas, 0, 0);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        let animationFrameId;

        const render = () => {
            draw(ctx)
            animationFrameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(render)
        }
        render();
        
        return () => {
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameId);
        }
    }, [ draw ]);

    return (
        <canvas
            ref={ canvasRef }
            onMouseDown={ e => console.log(master, e) }
        />
    );
};
```

**Edited for clarity based on comments**

In my attempts to render the `master.canvas` directly (e.g. `return master.canvas;` in `<Canvas>`), I get some variation of the error "Objects cannot be React children" or I get `[object HTMLCanvasElement]` verbatim on the screen.

It feels redundant to take the `#offScreen` canvas and repaint it each frame.  Is there, instead, a way to *insert* or *append* `#offScreen` into `<Canvas>`, so that react is just directly utilizing `#offScreen` without having to repaint it into the react component canvas via the ref?

*Specific Issue:* Functionally, I'm rendering a canvas twice--once off screen and once in the react component.  How do I (replace/append?) the component's `<canvas>` element with the offscreen canvas (`#offScreen`), instead of repainting it like I'm doing now?

Comment: OK, it's clearer what you're trying to do after the update. Thanks. The overall architecture here seems strange--you have a `Canvas` element that somehow receives a `<canvas>` element in its props? Seems like the `<canvas>` tag should be an implementation detail of `Canvas` component, not something controlled by a parent. The solution would be removing `canvas` from the `master` prop. If you want to draw on an already-rendered canvas from `master`, then this seems like it shouldn't be a component but rather a "vanilla" helper function within another component that simply does drawing.

Comment: @ggorlen This is not possible, as the `master.canvas` is exactly that--the source of truth and all the actual painting is facilitated by several worker classes behind the scenes; thus the use of a `Context`.  React is meant to be a shell to actually get it to the DOM, as the `master.canvas` also exposes a `stream` behind the scenes that React shouldn't have anything to do with.

Comment: OK, so it seems this "component" is really just a vanilla helper function to perform some drawing, not a legitimate component on the screen that needs to render anything. The `requestAnimationFrame` loop seems like it should be in whatever parent component controls the canvas element (I assume you only have one render loop for this canvas....).

Comment: The react component has **no purpose except** to draw an existing canvas to the DOM.  What I have above is just *a* way that makes it happen, but it seems excessive to paint the same thing twice--once off screen and once in react--and this is what I'm trying to avoid doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, this was actually fairly straightforward, as I overcomplicated it substantially.

```
export function Canvas({ canvas, ...rest }) {
    const container = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        container.current.innerHTML = "";
        container.current.append(canvas);
    }, [ container, canvas ]);

    return (
        <div ref={ container } />
    )
}
```